# How to detect a handle leak in c# app

Tags: c#, .net, handle, handle-leak

In my C# app , when it run i can see clearly in the windows task manager that the 
count of handle columns is steadly increase.
The memory is fine and not increase , only the handle arrive to very high level.

How can i debug this leak , detect it and solve the handle leak.

Thanks!

Comment: Any 3rd party UI controls? can you explain the application structure a bit more, there isn't enough information here

Comment: There is no 3party UI controls. I think this is not linked to UI and the leak is come from the logic. the app is very big and complex this is a little hard to explain her stracture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you obtain Current Window Handle Count and Window Handle Limit in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143206/how-do-you-obtain-current-window-handle-count-and-window-handle-limit-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is something that you're going to debug; it's something you're going to find with code inspection. Possible causes:

1. Failing to dispose of GDI objects. Are you using WinForms? Do you have `using` statements on every brush and pen?
2. Is your thread count going up with the handle count? Are you starting threads that never complete?
3. Are you using LogonUser? CloseHandle? You have to be very careful disposing user handles. If you pass the logon handle to WindowsIdentity, you should dispose the handle right after passing it to WindowsIdentity (on the same thread it was created on.)
4. Are you using SqlConnection? It's pool maintains open handles. Maybe something is not right there.

Ages ago I had an issue where I was disposing a LogonUser handle late. In fact, the user had disconnected and the handle had been closed automatically. I would thereafter call CloseHandle on what I thought was the handle. However, the handle slots in .NET are reused. They are almost always valid, but you cannot tell what kind of object is in a given slot. I was actually closing SqlConnection pool objects inadvertently.